# BOOT_COMPLETED intents received even though no boot took place

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, reboot

Hey there, 
has anyone else discovered that sometimes BOOT_COMPLETED intents arrive out of nowhere?

I have created an OnBootRecoverReceiver which starts a service after it received a BOOT_COMPLETED intent from android - works fine so far... but in some (yet not traceable) events i receive such an intent even though there was no reboot at all.

Anyone has a clue about that, or had the same problem before?

The Manifest entry for the receiver:

```
    <receiver android:name=".trigger.OnBootRecoverReceiver">  
        <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />  
        </intent-filter>  
    </receiver>`
```

Receiver Code:

```
public class OnBootRecoverReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
    serviceIntent.setAction("de.android.stuff.trigger.OnBootRecoverService");
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
}

}
```

If anyone has a idea, please feel free to help.

Comment: I'd get rid of the `HOME` category from the `<intent-filter>`, as it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To clear things up here: there was no BOOT_COMPLETED intent created anywhere

For some reason the Service (which is startet by the Receiver) crashed on the particular device some time ago. Our good friend the android ActivityManager then decided to re-animate the said Service:

```
03-16 12:00:02.239: WARN/ActivityManager(2504): Scheduling restart of crashed service de.ukn.hci.android.diary/.trigger.OnBootRecoverService in 5000ms
```

Which of course led to me thinking the Recevier was fired again, but - as it turns out there was just the Service starting again. Without any REBOOT intent whatsoever.

**Solution** to stop this:
Add a boolean Extra to the intent created by the Receiver

```
serviceIntent.putExtra("isFromReceiver", true);
context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

Then check for this boolean Extra while in onStart(Intent) of the Service

```
    boolean isFromReceiver = intent.getBooleanExtra("isFromReceiver", false);
    if( !isFromReceiver ) {
        return; //just stop starting the service
    }
```